# Javascript Binding Nested Function in Object to Root Object

Tags: javascript

We have this kind of situation where we need to bind a nested function within an object to the object itself. when we try to bind the function to `this` it is being binded to the window instead...

```js
var a = {
  b: [{
    onclick: function() {
      console.log(this)
    }.bind(this)
  }]
}

a.b[0].onclick() // this = window
```

Is there any possible way of biding the scope of `b[0].onclick` to object `a` without have to use `call` and `apply` when calling the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `b` a getter rather than a direct reference to an array. This will allow you to use lexical binding and an arrow function to access `a` as `this`. Callers should be none the wiser:

```js
var a = {
  name: "My Name",
  get b() {
    return [{
      onclick: () => {
        console.log("this name:", this.name)
      }
    }]
  }
}

a.b[0].onclick() // this = a
```

Comment: We are working with standalone IE>=9 customers, in our case, some day, hopefully soon, this will deserve green check Mark...

Answer (score 2):

After `a` has been declared, `bind` the onclick to `a`, once, and then every time the onclick is invoked, the calling context will be `a`:

```js
var a = {
  b: [{
    onclick: function() {
      console.log(this)
    }
  }]
};
a.b[0].onclick = a.b[0].onclick.bind(a);

a.b[0].onclick()
```

You can also define the function after declaring `a`:

```js
var a = {
  b: [{
  }]
};
a.b[0].onclick = function() {
  console.log(this);
}.bind(a);

a.b[0].onclick()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but if this was the case we could also use call and apply... is there a possible solution to bind this from within the object upon instantiation?

Comment: The problem with `.call` and `.apply` is that you'd have to use those methods *every time* you wanted to call the function with the desired calling context of `a`. Using `.bind` allows you to create a new function with the desired calling context *once*, so you don't have to `.call` or `.apply` every time you want to run the function.

Comment: The object has not yet been created when its contents are being defined, so it's not possible to `.bind` inside the object literal itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps. First, create the object, then add the methods that you bind to it :

```js
const a = {};

a.b = [{
    onclick: function() {
      console.log(this)
    }.bind(a)
  }];

a.b[0].onclick();
```